# Why did the lady die?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

There was an IQ test created by Random Person. A contestant attempts to answer all the questions but fails the last one. Here goes the conversation:

> **Random Person:** You have 500 bricks in the plane. You drop one out. How many do you have left?
>
> **Contestant:** Easy. 499 bricks.
>
> **Random Person:** What three steps are needed to put an elephant into a fridge?
>
> **Contestant:** Open the fridge, put the elephant inside, and close it.
>
> **Random Person:** Now what four steps are needed to put the deer inside the fridge?
>
> **Contestant:** Easy, open the fridge, take out the elephant, put in the deer, then finally, close the fridge.
>
> **Troll:** The Lion King's party had every animal but who?
>
> **Contestant:** The deer
>
> **Random Person:** The old lady crosses the river filled with crocodiles. How does she do it?
>
> **Contestant:** All the crocodiles are at the Lion King's party
>
> **Random Person:** But she still dies afterwards. Why?
>
> **Contestant:** Uhhh, she falls into a lava pit?
>
> **Random Person:** Haha! You have failed the test! Now get out of here! IQ score: 0/100

How did the lady die from crossing the river? She made it to the other side, not eaten and not injured from crossing the river.

Comment: [questions on troll](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10466/the-traveler-and-the-blood-thirsty-troll?rq=1) always had bad conditions here.

Comment: i was just kidding buddy...u took it seriously..

Comment: Apparently, the troll trolled me...

Comment: reason of the downvotes is that this question is very simple. As I said in earlier comment (which is now deleted) "i did this question years ago"

Comment: Or perhaps the reason for downvotes is... [that trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrickJoke)....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because

> The brick (from the plane) fell on her head.

Comment: just 14 seconds late.

Comment: Darn it.  I didn't think my typing was so slow that I needed to refresh.  Oh well.

Comment: i meant i was 14 seconds late...

Answer (score 14):

The old lady died afterwards because

> Everyone dies eventually, and she was old so her death within a reasonably short time was expected anyway. She died in her sleep, painlessly and of natural causes.

Answer (score 1):

the brick from the plane fell on her head

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! An answer identical to this one has already been given, and usually it is considered best to not post an answer unless it adds something not found in other answers or improves on them. Good luck and happy puzzling! :)